# Cloud Firestore spark free plan limit

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

As the google confirmation Cloud Firestore has moved out of beta and is now generally available. they offered for spark free limit as below.

```
Stored data  1 GB total
Bandwidth 10GB/month
Document writes 20K/day
Document reads 50K/day
Document deletes  20K/day
```

I didn't understand Document writes 20K/day and reads 50K/day.

**Is that 20K/day means 20KiloBytes per Day?**

Comment: 20K means 20,000 reads per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that 20K/day means 20KiloBytes per Day?

No, it means 20.000 (twenty thousand) read operations per day. It has nothing to do with Kilobytes.

Comment: That means I can execute write query only for 20,000 times per day?

Comment: Yes, that right, but this is happening only in case of Spark Plan. If you want to have higher limits, you should consider to upgrade the plan to Flame or Blaze Plan. I personally use the last one because you pay as you go.